# arc and no-arc issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

This is my code

```
__weak KDObject *obj = [KDObject fetchObj] ;
NSLog(@"%@", obj) ; // I think it should be nil, but it is not
obj.i = 10 ;
NSLog(@"%d", obj.i) ;
```

In `KDObject.m`

```
@implementation KDObject    
+ (instancetype)fetchObj
{
    return [[self alloc] init] ;
}
@end
```

the result is the same whatever KDOjbect.m is compile with `-fno-objc-arc` flag or without `-fno-objc-arc` flag

Anybody has ideas why `obj` is not nil ?

Comment: Why do you think it should be nil? You initialized a KDObject, which won't give back a nil object.

Comment: Because `obj` is weak, if you do like this `__weak KDObject *o = [[KDObject alloc] init] ;`, o is nil.

Comment: But it's not a class variable, and __weak is totally unnececarry

Comment: In my case, the instance returned nil as expected.

Comment: @trick14 Show me your code please.

Comment: ARC makes no promises about the time when the object would be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to your Q *and* to your answer:

-fectchObject is a method not belonging to any method family with ownership transfer. Therefore ARC has to ensure that returning the reference is safe. That means that losing the strong reference in the local scope of -fetchObject does not give up the last reference.

*One* way to accomplish this is to use the autorelease pool. But ARC does not guarantee that the ARP is used. Moreover it tries *not* to use the ARP, because it is the solution with the highest memory pressure.

So the things happening depends of the compiler implementation, attributes set to the method and what the compiler sees in source code  (esp. implementation of -fetchObject). So you should not rely on returning in ARP.

__weak is guaranteed to be nil, if the object is destroyed. But it is not guaranteed that the object is destroyed in the earliest possible moment. This is subject of optimization.

Comment: I'm confused now. __weak will not increase retain count. right? It means that    __weak KDObject *obj = [KDObject fetchObj] ; will released just after the instance created. I tested with the similar code KudoCC asked, and the instances returned nil. Also there was a warning that object will be released after assignment.

Comment: @KudoCC The way, ARC returns the reference from -fetchObject is implementation detail. You cannot assume that it is done in ARP nor that it is released immediately. ARC tries do this early (i. e. at the end of the full expression), but cannot guarantee whether or under which circumstances the ARP is used (= later release.)

Comment: From the docs: "When returning from such a function or method, ARC retains the value at the point of evaluation of the return statement, then leaves all local scopes, and then balances out the retain while ensuring that the value lives across the call boundary. In the *worst case*, this may involve an *autorelease*, but callers *must not assume* that the value is actually in the autorelease pool."

Answer (score 0):

From the docs about  __weak

> __weak specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive. A weak reference is set to nil when there are no strong
>   references to the object.

Whether it's __weak or not `KDObject *o = [[KDObject alloc] init]` creates an object so `o` is not nil.

__weak is something realated to memory management. If none of strong objects are pointing to a `weak` object, it would be released from memory.

Comment: have you tried the code ? You can try it with `__weak UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init] ;`, and v is nil without doubt.

Comment: That because you are assigning a retained object to a weak variable. It is released after assignment.

Comment: Ridiculous! Do you mean it will send the instance release when I assign it to a weak variable ?

Comment: Yes, just type above line in in XCode and see the warning XCode gives you. It says the same thing.

Comment: If it is , v will be released after assigned to v2, but it is not. `UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init] ; __weak UIView *v2 = v ;`

Comment: Hey buddy, you say that in `__weak KDObject *obj = [KDObject fetchObj] ;` , you get obj nil, but in mine is not nil, I think it maybe we have the different version of compiler. Which version is your XCode compiler ?

Comment: Yes, `v` here is not a retained object, that's why.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)loadView
{
 [super loadView];

    TestObject *obj_ = [[TestObject alloc] init];
    pObj = obj_;
    if(pObj == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"pObj_ is not nil");
    }

    __weak TestObject *obj2_ = [[TestObject alloc] init];
    if(obj2_ == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"obj2_ is nil");
    }

    __weak TestObject *obj3_ = [TestObject createInstance];
    if(obj3_ == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"obj3_ is nil");
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(pObj == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"pObj is nil");
    }
}
```

KudoCC requested this code. I used LLVM5.1. If I use -fno-objc-arc to TestObject.h, the objc3_ became not nil.

Comment: creteInstance is same as your fetchObj()

Comment: obj3_ is nil ? It's weird... Can you try to compile KDOjbect.m with -fno-objc-arc flag ?

Comment: Which version is your compiler ? It's LLVM 5.1 on mine.

Comment: In non-ARC, the obj3_ was not nil. Was __weak only for ARC? I have no idea why the result of obj2_ and obj3_ are different. obj2_ was still nil in non-ARC.

Comment: Throwing just a piece of code is considered a bad attitude here. Add some explanation etc. Your answer has been flagged as low quality and to be deleted. Please, improve it to prevent deletion.

Comment: Sorry about that. The code I added was what KudoCC requested. It was too long to add as a comment.